# Liquibase for/for each operation (migrating table data)

Tags: sql, liquibase

I'm using Liquibase and I need to insert data in one table, depending on the entries in another (create a foreign key reference)

```
Table: Entities (currently empty)
PK id
INT data

Table: Existing_table (contains data)
PK id
... data
FK entities_id (references Entities.id)
```

for each entry in `Existing_table` I need to insert a value in `Entities` and update `entities_id` in `Existing_table`, using the created `Entities.id key`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `insert into entities ... select ... from existing_table where ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, in plain sql that would put data in Entities table. How do you update each entry in Existing_table with the freshly generated key? Like: insert into Entities .. values({newKey}, someValues). update Existing_table set entities_id={newKey}.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This is not really a Liquibase question, but a plain SQL question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, there are 4 that are on support now: Oracle, MySql, PostgreSQL, Linter. I thought about a solution with a temopary column in Entries, containg an id frim Existing_table. So it would be removed after migration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to make a parametrised loop, so used a temopary column for storing   referenced id.

```
<changeSet id="add temp_column to Entities" author="">
    <addColumn tableName="Entities">
        <column name="temp_id" type="BIGINT"></column>
    </addColumn>
 </changeSet>

<changeSet author="" id="insert Existing_table keys into Entities">
    <sql>
        INSERT INTO Entities(type_id, temp_id)
        select 1, id
        from Existing_table;
    </sql>
</changeSet>

<changeSet author="" id="insert entity keys into Existing_table">
    <sql>
        UPDATE Existing_table d set entity_id = ent.id
        FROM (select id, temp_id
        from Entities) ent
        where ent.temp_id = d.id;
    </sql>
</changeSet>


<changeSet id="drop temp_column to Entities" author="">
    <dropColumn tableName="Entities"
                columnName="temp_id"/>
</changeSet>



<changeSet author="" id="addNotNullConstraint Existing_table-Entities">
    <addNotNullConstraint columnDataType="BIGINT"
                          columnName="entity_id"
                          tableName="Existing_table"/>
</changeSet>
```